# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, downgrade

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, but now I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with Ubuntu 14.04

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want that?

Comment: I want to install edX . edX is supported for ubuntu12.04 not for ubuntu 14 so i want to istal it okay

Comment: @PraveenKorrapati why don't you write this in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think that... unless you intend to get into VMware, what you need to do is install 12.04 "side by side" with 14.04 in separate partitions, so that what you will have is a dual boot.  This is easier than you might think.  If you boot to an ubuntu live 12.04 and select install, it will detect the current installation and offer you the choice of installing 12.04 alongside the current installation.  It will then proceed to partition the hard drive to make room for the new installation.

If instead you are literally interested in making 12.04 run UNDER 14.04, then you need to enter the Ubuntu Software Center, and type "virtualbox", sans quotes.  Virtualbox is remarkably easy to figure out and use, and I've found that the online tutorials for Oracle vmware for Windows appear to apply to this application as well.

I've never actually installed any versions of ubuntu, under virtualbox, only versions of Windows, but I suppose you have your reasons.